# Why is nonlocal keyword being 'interrupted' by a global keyword?

Tags: python, scope

I'm a beginner programmer trying to learn python, and I have come across the topic of scopes. I came across the error 'no binding for nonlocal var_name found' when executing the bottom-most code. Can someone explain why is the nonlocal keyword unable to 'look past' the intermediate function and into the outer function?

```py
#this works
globe = 5


def outer():
    globe = 10
    def intermediate():

        def inner():
            nonlocal globe
            globe = 20
            print(globe)
        inner()
        print(globe)
    intermediate()
    print(globe)


outer()
```

```py
globe = 5


def outer():
    globe = 10
    def intermediate():
        global globe #but not when I do this
        globe = 15
        def inner():
            nonlocal globe #I want this globe to reference 10, the value in outer()
            globe = 20
            print(globe)
        inner()
        print(globe)
    intermediate()
    print(globe)


outer()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions involving the `nonlocal` keyword will cause Python to try to find the variable in the enclosing local scopes, until it first encounters the first specified variable **name**.

The `nonlocal globe` expression will have a look if there is a variable named `globe` in the `intermediate` function. It will encounter it, in the `global` scope however, so it will presume it has reached the module scope and finished searching for it without finding a `nonclocal` one, hence the exception.

By declaring the `global globe` in the `intermediate` function you pretty much closed the path to reach any `nonlocal` variables with the same name in the previous scopes. You can have a look at the discussion [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue32361) why was it "decided" to be implemented this way in Python.

If you want to make sure that the variable `globe` is or is not within the local scope of some function, you can use the `dir()` functions, because from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local
>   scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes
>   for that object.

Comment: Although to be fair the `nonlocal` docs (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) mention that `The nonlocal statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope excluding globals.`, so according to it the globals should be ignored, but they don't seem to be.